# How can I separate HH and MM in datetime in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I saved the datetime in my model and now

I have this ---> Feb. 1, 2020, 10:11 p.m.

How can I reach this? --->  10:11 p.m

Comment: `mydatetime.time()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138744/extract-time-from-datetime-and-determine-if-time-not-date-falls-within-range may suit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [**`.time()`** method [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) to retrieve the time object:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime(1958, 3, 25, 12, 34).time()
datetime.time(12, 34)
```