# Extracting hh:mm:ss from a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract hh:mm:ss from a column

```
Column1 Column 2 Column 3
1        2     12:30:11
2        3     1904-01-01 13:40:20
3        4     20:03:04
```

In column three there are some entries starting with 1904-01-01.
I just want to get hh:mm:ss from the column.

Comment: does this help? -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/16138744/8279585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values are strings filter last 8 values:

```
df['Column 3'] = df['Column 3'].str[-8:]
print (df)
   Column1 Column 2  Column 3
1                 2  12:30:11
2                 3  13:40:20
3                 4  20:03:04
```

Or convert to datetimes and get `HH:MM:SS` format:

```
df['Column 3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column 3']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

A safe way is to use a regex, thus if you have NaN or non-aligned strings (e.g. trailing space), you'll get exactly what you want:

```
df['Column 3'] = df['Column 3'].str.extract('(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})')
```

output:

```
   Column1  Column 2  Column 3
0        1         2  12:30:11
1        2         3  13:40:20
2        3         4  20:03:04
```